# Can't play audio files in localhost

Tags: javascript

here is my code to play audio file in localhost and got error as "Could not open location; you might not have permission to open the file." please help me Thnx in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <center>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            function getPath() {
                playId.src = "/root/Desktop/103.mp3";
            }
        </script>
    </center>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="submit" value="PLAY PATH" onclick="getPath()" />
    <embed height="50" width="100" id="playId">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<center>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

 
function getPath() {


playId.src = "/root/Desktop/103.mp3"; 
}
 
</script>
</center>
  </head>
<body>
<input type="submit" value="PLAY PATH" onclick="getPath()" />
<embed height="50" width="100" id="playId" >
</body>
</html>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your question, use the "edit" link under the question rather than posting a comment. I've copied your HTML into the question for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`playId` is not defined. You need to find the element, and then set the attribute.

```
document.getElementById('playId').src = "/root/Desktop/103.mp3";
```

Also, you probably need to set it to a local `file://` URL if it isn't already.